# Rails field set to readonly - how do you notify the user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a field in a form where I grab the Active directory user name and put it in the field. I want to display it to the user and store it in the sql data table.

```
        <td> <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :ad_author %><br>
        <!-- The field below is populated from AD (or perhaps the user table) if the user is logged in    -->
      <!-- \\TODO need ot add logic here in case the user isn't logged in.    -->
      <%= f.text_field :ad_author, :value => current_user.name, readonly => true %>
    </div></td>
```

I have the text field set to readonly which does not allow the user to change it. However, the user isn't notified. It just stores the active directory name but doesn't change the field in the data table (which is what I want).

I'm not sure how to go about this.

is there a way to display the user name and store it in the sql table ?

Comment: When the form is submitted you are getting user's name as `ad_author`, then you can manipulate your database, can't you?

Comment: can you show us your controller code?

Comment: " However, the user isn't notified." What do you mean? What do you mean by "notified"??

I could probably answer your question but I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I took the approach that sadaf2605 mentioned. I set the field to readonly and just changed the label to say 'view only'.    

By notified, what I meant was that adding :readonly to the field simply prevented changes. It didn't let the user know that the field was read only.  Changing the label fixes that.